# ASP.NET Core DI: how to inject a service through lambda without specifying the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Suppose we've got the following class:

```
 class MyOptions{
    public IManager MyManager { get; set; }
 }
```

Currently, there are two implementations of the `IManager` interface. Lets call them ManagerA and ManagerB:

```
class ManagerA:IManager {}
class ManagerB:IManager {}
```

During startup, I will only be interested in creating a single object of type `ManagerA` or `ManagerB` and that instance will be accessible through the `MyOptions.MyManager` property. Does anyone know how to register that with the ASP.NET Core dependency injection system? I've tried using a lambda during startup:

```
builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
   ServiceDescriptor.Scope<IGestorCertificados>(ctx => myOptions.MyManager));
```

Even though it compiles, I'll end up with an exception at runtime:

> Implementation type cannot be 'IManager' because it is indistinguishable from other services registered for 'IManager'.

Can anyone help? How do you fix this? Do I really need to refactor my code so that the lambda explictly returns type A or type B?

Thanks

Luis

Comment: How do you determine which manager is needed at start up

Comment: Yes. The DI container has to know how to resolve `IManager` with a concrete type. It can't make that decision for you, so you have to tell it which you want.

Comment: It depends on the properties that have been set up in the options. MyOptions's MyManager property is initialised through a post configure options helper.

Comment: @ChrisPratt even if I'm using a lambda?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Hello again Chris. Well, since I'm using a lambda to instantiate an object, I'm not sure on why it's important to specify the  type. For instance, with autofac, I'm under the impression that I'd be able to do something like this: builder.Register<IManager>(ctx => new ManagerA() ) adn everything would work ok...

Comment: What you ask is unclear. How do you resolve `MyOptions` at the place where you need it? Part of your question seems to suggest `MyOptions` is used as a static class...

Comment: Hello Wouter. What I want is simple: I have a factory which returns ManagerA or ManagerB, but the instance is returned as IManager. I thought that using a lambda to instantiate the object would be enough, but it seems like that's not the case...unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

> During startup, I will only be interested in creating a single object of type ManagerA or ManagerB

This implies that which class to use is known at startup, which typically means this value is specified in a configuration file.

What you should do is read the configuration value and register either one of the manager classes. For instance:

```
string manager = configuration["manager"];

switch (manager)
{
    case "A": services.AddTransient<IManager, ManagerA>();
    case "B": services.AddTransient<IManager, ManagerB>();
    default: throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Unknown value " + manager);
}
```